# How to auto size pgfplots legend in beamer's overlays?

Tags: beamer, pgfplots

I would like to gradually add plots to a graph using slide overlays. I figured how to do it. However, the legend doesn't behave the way I want. pgfplots sets the size of the legend box the same on all slides, equal to its maximum. IMHO it looks ugly on the first slides.

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat = 1.18
  , cycle list/Dark2-8
  }

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotsset{
                width             =  \textwidth
              , height            =  0.7\textwidth
              , grid            = major
              , every axis plot/.append style = {
                    line width = 1.5pt
                  , no markers
                  , domain     = 0:1
                  , samples    = 500
                  }
            }
            \begin{axis}[
                xmin = 0
              , xmax = 1
              , legend style = {
                    anchor = north west
                  , at     = {(0.05, 0.95)}
                  , font   = \scriptsize
                  }
              , legend cell align = {left}
              ]
                \addplot+
                    coordinates {
                        (0, 0)
                        (0.45, 0)
                        (0.55, 1)
                        (1, 1)
                    };
                \addlegendentry{1}
                \addplot+[
                    samples    = 2
                  , visible on = <2->]{-0.135557 + 1.27111 * x};
                \addlegendentry[visible on = <2->]{a long legend line}
                \addplot+[visible on = <3->]
                    {0.0734743 - 2.49145 * x + 10.0335 * x^2 - 6.68901 * x^3};
                \addlegendentry[visible on = <3->]{3}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is how the chart on the first slide looks like:

[image]

I would want this:

[image]

Then this:

[image]

and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\only<>{...}` to completely remove the legend entry on the other overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
%\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat = 1.18
  , cycle list/Dark2-8
  }

\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotsset{
                width             =  \textwidth
              , height            =  0.7\textwidth
              , grid            = major
              , every axis plot/.append style = {
                    line width = 1.5pt
                  , no markers
                  , domain     = 0:1
                  , samples    = 500
                  }
            }
            \begin{axis}[
                xmin = 0
              , xmax = 1
              , legend style = {
                    anchor = north west
                  , at     = {(0.05, 0.95)}
                  , font   = \scriptsize
                  }
              , legend cell align = {left}
              ]
                \addplot+
                    coordinates {
                        (0, 0)
                        (0.45, 0)
                        (0.55, 1)
                        (1, 1)
                    };
                \addlegendentry{1}
                \addplot+[
                    samples    = 2
                  , visible on = <2->]{-0.135557 + 1.27111 * x};
                \only<2->{\addlegendentry{a long legend line}}
                \addplot+[visible on = <3->]
                    {0.0734743 - 2.49145 * x + 10.0335 * x^2 - 6.68901 * x^3};
                \only<3->{\addlegendentry{3}}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]